# 'This is speaking' is correct on the telephone

Tags: sentence-meaning, spoken-english

When you answer the phone, I'm wondering if 'This is speaking' is correct instead of 'This is he speaking.'
please tell me the correct expression.

Comment: Non-native opinion: I wouldn’t understand either of those sentences. “Yes, that’s me” is what I would naturally use.

Comment: Whatever it should have been, it's been worn down to "speaking" by native speakers.

Comment: [Is this the party to whom I am speaking?](https://youtu.be/RFz2iFMygSg)

Comment: You need to clarify the context a bit. To me, "answering the phone" means that it starts ringing, you have no idea who it is (assuming a classic land line), you pick up the handset and say something. In this case I don't think you'd ever say "This is speaking", even if it was correct. On the other hand, if they call you, you answer without saying your name, and they say they want to speak with <your name>, then an answer like "this is speaking", *though incorrect*, makes sense. I think you could [edit] the question to clarify that you refer to the second case, not to the first one.

Comment: I am not sure whether "This is speaking" is grammatically correct, but I can assure you that no native English speaker would understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 20):

You wouldn't normally refer to yourself as "this" without using a personal pronoun in the predicate. I usually say, "This is she," but my usage is probably a bit overly correct. Probably, most people say "That's me." (Even though the objective "me" is technically incorrect here.)

Regardless, "this is speaking" is neither correct nor natural grammar.

Comment: Considering that a very large number of people consistently say "That's me" instead of, say, "This is (s)he", wouldn't it be fair to just accept that "That's me" *is* correct?

Comment: @Clearer I accept that it is correct in terms of descriptive grammar, but if someone is trying to learn the general rules of English grammar, I don't know how to explain that a copula should usually take a predicate nominative, and sometimes people will think you're uneducated if you use an objective in the predicate, but sometimes, it's so common no one will blink. If you know the rules for breaking the rules, please feel free to expound!

Comment: @joiedevivre I feel that in almost all contexts nowadays, "to be" is much more regular than it once was, in that it takes a subject and an object that are declined as such. "It's me" is so much more common to hear than "it is I", and I'm struggling to think of any examples where the nominative sounds better/less wrong to me than the objective. All such uses just sound archaic these days.

Comment: @Muzer You have a good point. The only real exceptions I can think of are when predicate nominatives are followed by "who" clauses. _It is he who doesn't like the bread._ It's a bit of a meta question, though. If what people actually say most often isn't what's considered correct in textbooks (and so might conflict with what English language learners have been told), should we add a caveat? I haven't looked at the meta for the site yet. Maybe this is already in there.

Comment: `'Tis I!` if you want to *really* be dramatic about it.

Comment: @Muzer Nominative is correct in Latin (and probably derivative languages like French and Spanish, I don't know). Accusative ("objective") is correct in germanic languages, like German and the Scandinavian languages. English is an amalgam, so it's difficult to say what is truly "correct".

Comment: It isn't a matter of whether it's "correct" to say "this is he/she/" or "that's me" [it's at least arguable that the latter is incorrect under certain prescriptive rules, but as another commenter points out, the construction's ubiquity makes it "correct" in a certain sense], but that it's considered by many to be more formal to use the first construction.  It also provides more information to the caller, particularly the speaker's preferred gender identification.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1771/

Comment: @Arthur Actually, Swedish speakers more consistently use the nominative case with "to be" than English speakers; in this case, "Det är jag" instead of "Det är mig." I don't know whether this is ancestral or borrowed from Romance languages, or how it is in the other Scandinavian languages.

Comment: Where is it taught that "me" is incorrect in that situation? That's totally normal English for everyone I know.

Answer (score 9):

Like @joiedevivre, I was taught from an early age to say *[This is he](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4032)*, but this is rather formal, deriving from centuries of directive that only nominative pronouns should follow a copula. In practice, this is unnatural for a native speaker; a well-educated person who is careful to state *that is he* in writing will say *that's him* in casual conversation and not think twice about it. The nominative forms are nowadays used almost exclusively as subjects.

On the other hand, *This is he* is far better than *It is I*, which may provoke uncontrollable laughter unless you are quoting the Bible, or perhaps a comic book superhero.

There is no single formula for responding to a question like *May I speak to Jinsook?* or *Is Jinsook available?* Any of the following might be acceptable:

> This is Jinsook speaking.
>
> You're speaking to Jinsook / You're speaking to her.
>
> Jinsook speaking.
>
> Speaking.
>
> This is Jinsook.
>
> This is she.
>
> This is.
>
> Jinsook here. (not *Jinsook is here*)
>
> I'm Jinsook / I am Jinsook.
>
> That would be me.
>
> That's me.

You can insert *Yes* in front of any of these, with a pause, and some people will also use them in combination with one another, separated by a pause. Thus, if you have heard other people saying *This is speaking*, it may have been a conflation of two separate responses that should have been separated:

> This is, speaking

Comment: No. "This is." would not be used by a native speaker. Nor would a native speaker say "This is speaking", with or without the comma.

Comment: As a native speaker, I have heard and used "This is." It seems to have an implied "this is [that person]". There is a slightly elevated emphasis on the "is" (the "this" is still emphasized more than the the "is"), as in "I don't need to go get that person because this _is_ that person".

Comment: Maybe there's a dialect difference going on here. There should be a general rule on this site if there isn't already that *advice on colloquial usage should always be labelled with dialects known to use it*. As a UK native, if someone said "this is", I'd reply with a confused "this is what?"

Comment: *This is* is not usual, but also not remarkable in AmE. Obviously, this is a wide range of *possible* responses. What may be appropriate is not only related to locale, but the setting; for example, I might respond differently on my mobile as opposed to my work lines.

Comment: @choster The OP also didn't specify the exact question being asked. It's easy to see how "This is" is a legitimate answer to "Is this Jinsook?"

Comment: It's very common to just say "This is Bob" or whatever your name is, without saying speaking.

Comment: Upvoted specifically for "This is..." and "Speaking" which are the two most common usages in my experience.

Comment: I've used "It is" by itself (not "this is"), but only in response to an "Is this Bobson?"

Answer (score 6):

`This is speaking` in any way sounds incorrect to me.

*In addition,*

If **you** are answering the call, you don't refer yourself as a 'third person!' So, it should be 'This is Jinsook Lee speaking.'

However, I'd refrain myself using that, and rather would go with the commonest one:

> *This is Jinsook...*

Comment: Or one can just say "Speaking" and be done with it

Comment: @CinCout *exactly!* I do that! :)

Comment: Another possible common variant to "this is Jinsook" would be "I'm Jinsook."

Comment: It is also common, more in business settings, to just say "Jinsook speaking." It's usually not a response, but something you say when you first come on the line, either answering the phone or someone being transferred to you. For example, "Corporate accounting, Bob speaking," or just "Bob speaking" if it's Bob's office and someone was just transferred there, or "Thank you for calling Some Business, Larry speaking" when answering the phone.

Comment: Also on a tangent, the "anyway" in the answer above is incorrect. "Anyway" is a word, but it is not _this_ word. In the context above, it should be two separate words, "in any way." The word "anyway" has a specific different meaning, similar to "besides" or "even though". I see this kind of thing a lot with phrases like "a lot" (there is no word "alot", and the word "allot" has a different meaning) and "any time".

Comment: Ironically, if you say "this is speaking" out loud, it's always a true statement.  Just not the one the OP intends to make.

Comment: *If you are answering the call, you don't refer yourself as a 'third person!' * That is not really correct in US or UK English - we will say "This is he".

Comment: @stangdon if stangdon calls me and I pick up the call, I'll *never* say, 'this is *he!* Nor does anyone in US/UK would say that!

Comment: @MaulikV - "Nor does anyone in US/UK would say that"?!  I am a native US English speaker, living in the US, and yes, I can confirm that people here in the US do say that. [You can find numerous references to it.](https://www.google.com/search?q="this+is+he") You are flatly incorrect in your statement.

Comment: @stangdon [the highest voted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56295/how-to-answer-is-this-john-on-phone) here *agrees* that natives don't prefer that.

Comment: @MaulikV - The highest voted answer at that link says nothing about "This is he", they're talking about "*It* is he."  Again, trust me: I am a native US English speaker: people say "This is he."

Comment: So, if you are answering, you call yourself 'he' while answering? @stangdon This is really new for me!

Answer (score 1):

I definitely concur with Bob, and disagree with Maulik V about not using the third person.  On the phone is about the only place I find using the third person about me as a natural thing, normally when specifying who in the household or business is "on the phone".

"ACME Industries, Ted speaking." would be a perfectly acceptable opening, as would:

"ACME Industries, this is Ted"

You could stretch it out by saying:

"ACME Industries, this is Ted speaking"

but you cannot abbreviate it, by removing the name.  "This is he" works as a confirmation of who is on the line, but it is still a bit awkward, but "This is him" is even moreso.  Talking on the phone does not always involve natural language. We often use hand gestures while on the phone.  While that may be natural, it is not very useful.

Comment: Do we really have common understanding of [what is *third person!*](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/third_person.htm) in grammar?

Comment: I don't know.  Do we?  I think using a name is usually 2nd or 3rd person, but the usage does not fall directly in line with our use of pronouns.  Examples: "Hey Ted" can be replaced by "Hey you", but "My name is Ted" cannot be replaced by "My name is me"..We do say third person pronoun, which must specify something (in addition to 3rd person). Perhaps it would be clearer if I said 3rd person reference. Again, telephonespeak is not identical to other speach. I read recently that referring to oneself by name is a Buddhist thing.  In this case, on the telephone, it is expedience.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here.

> Q: Is this John Smith?
>
> A: This is, speaking ...

makes perfect sense, but certainly isn't all that common. Simply saying "Speaking." as suggested by @CinCout is what I grew up hearing my father say on the phone, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am a native speaker, and I usually say "This is Bob"...I have heard "speaking" from time to time, and also "this is" but I have never ever heard "this is speaking"  the construction does not make any sense without the comma as suggested above, but even that would be extremely rare.  In informal situations "it's me" would probably be used, especially with younger people, but in business it would be considered very informal

Answer (score 0):

"This is speaking" sounds completely incorrect to me. I would wonder if I had misheard or missed part of the conversation due to a faulty phone line. "This is ..." would normally be used like:

> This is fun.
>
> *This* is a knife!

Personally I answer the phone with my full name and nothing else, so that the caller knows immediately they have reached me (assuming that is their goal). In your case you could say:

> Jinsook Lee.

Or variants:

> Jinsook here.
>
> Hello, Jinsook here.
>
> Jinsook Lee speaking.

---

Once again, don't say "This is speaking". If I heard that I might think you had said "Therese speaking" and wonder if I had dialed the wrong number.